# Pandas DateTime comparison not yielding accurate results

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a data frame where I am attempting to to filter the values where the value in the date column is between `StartDate` and `FinishDate`. To achieve this I create columns with `pandas.to_datetime` from the string values for these dates and then filter based on that.

```
    result['date'] = pd.to_datetime(result.DateCreated)
    result['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(result.StartDate)
    result['FinishDate'] = pd.to_datetime(result.FinishDate)
    result = result[(result.date >= result.StartDate) &
                    (result.date <= result.FinishDate)]
```

A partial portion of the Data used is below, the `StartDate` and `FinishDates` on the left are what the values are after the code above and the ones on the right are the initial values I included in case there was an issue in the `to_datetime`

```
,date,StartDate,FinishDate,startboundry,finishboundry,DateCreated,StartDate,FinishDate
0,2009-06-08,2009-05-01,2009-06-30,False,True,2009-06-08 00:00:00,2009-05-01,2009-06-30
1,2009-10-08,2009-08-01,2009-12-31,False,True,2009-10-08 00:00:00,2009-08-01,2009-12-31
2,2010-01-28,2010-01-01,2010-04-30,False,True,2010-01-28 00:00:00,2010-01-01,2010-04-30
3,2010-05-27,2010-05-01,2010-06-30,False,True,2010-05-27 00:00:00,2010-05-01,2010-06-30
4,2010-09-22,2010-08-01,2010-12-31,False,True,2010-09-22 00:00:00,2010-08-01,2010-12-31
5,2011-01-13,2011-01-01,2011-04-30,False,True,2011-01-13 00:00:00,2011-01-01,2011-04-30
6,2011-05-26,2011-05-01,2011-06-30,False,True,2011-05-26 00:00:00,2011-05-01,2011-06-30
7,2009-01-20,2009-01-01,2009-04-30,False,True,2009-01-20 00:00:00,2009-01-01,2009-04-30
8,2009-05-11,2009-05-01,2009-06-30,False,True,2009-05-11 00:00:00,2009-05-01,2009-06-30
9,2009-10-05,2009-08-01,2009-12-31,False,True,2009-10-05 00:00:00,2009-08-01,2009-12-31
```

Several of these are reading the initial condition of (`result.date >= result.StartDate`) as `False` even though they are clearly true.

2009-06-08 is after 2009-05-01 for example both in time and lexically if it was just doing a string comparison.

Edited to add some versioning information:
in the process of making sure versions of python pandas etc. were the same collected the version info to share in case that helps here:

pandas version 0.16.2
python version 2.7.9
ipython 3.2.0

Comment: Is it on purpose you have the columns 'StartDate' and 'FinishDate' twice?

Comment: yes, the second 2 are the original values before pd.to_dateframe which I included here in case they provided some insight.

Answer (score 0):

to filter your dataframe you can use between

```
df[df.date1.between(date2,date3)]
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?

Comment: would that just be date2, date3 or df.date2, df.date3? all the dates are rows in the database not just the date1

Comment: That gives the same results but it is useful to have a more streamlined version of the filter